# How To Filter Page Elements With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that I create using JS from API data.

I would like to filter the data based on two filter options: Location and Department.

I could do this pretty easily if it were just one filter option selected at any given time but sense any combination of filter options can be selected at any one time, i'm pretty lost.

So far my JS function to create each item on the page looks as such:

```
function createOffer(job){
        var $div = $('<div>', {'class': 'job-listing'});
        var $divDetails = $('<div>', {'class': 'job-listing__details'});
        var $title = $('<h2>'+job.title+'</h2>').addClass('job-listing__title');
        var $location = $('<span data-type="location" data-location="'+job.city+','+job.state+'">Location: </span>').addClass('job-listing__detail location');
        var $department = $('<span data-type="department" data-department="'+job.department+'">Department: </span>').addClass('job-listing__detail job-listing__detail--department department');
        var $viewMoreBtn = $('<a>+View Details</a>').addClass('job-listings__view-more');
        var $divViewMore = $('<div>', {'class': 'job-listing__more'});

        if(!allLocations.includes(job.city+','+job.state)){

            allLocations.push(job.city+','+job.state);

        }

        if(!allDepartments.includes(job.department)){
            allDepartments.push(job.department);
        }

        $div.append($title);
        $divDetails.append($location);
        $divDetails.append(''+job.city+','+job.state);
        $divDetails.append($department);
        $divDetails.append(''+job.department);
        $divViewMore.append(job.description);
        $div.append($divDetails);
        $div.append($divViewMore);
        $div.append($viewMoreBtn);
        allJobs.push($div);
        $jobsContainer.append($div);

    }
```

How would I go about filtering with two filter options all being able to select multiple filter options at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like that:

```
const $jobLocationFilter = $('#jobLocationFilter').val(); // Pretend it's a text field
const $jobDepartmentFilter = $('#jobDepartmentFilter ').val(); // Pretend it's a text field

const jobsFiltered = jobListFromDatabase.filter(job => 
     // If job location filter has value, filter by it, else includes this job (returns true)
    ( $jobLocationFilter ? job.location === $jobLocationFilter : true )
    && 
     // If job dep. filter has value, filter by it, summing with the previous filter
    ( $jobDepartmentFilter ? job.department === $jobDepartmentFilter : true )

    /* 
     And this could go on with multiple filters, 
     just adding && and another expression to filter. e.g:
       `
        ( $jobMinSalaryFilter ? job.salary >= $jobMinSalaryFilter : true )
         && 
         ... others
       `
    */
);

// Function to render the filtered jobs
renderJobs(jobsFiltered);
```